# RESTFul web service POST example

Tags: java, web-services, rest

Hi am actually learning about restful web service. I am starting with the basic of POSTing a word to another web application and display the word on the 2nd application.

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {`


    @Path("{f}")
      @GET
      @Produces("application/json")
      public Response PosttoInfo(@PathParam("f") String f) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        jsonObject.put("COMMAND", f); 


        String result = "\n\n POSTING to 2nd application : \n\n" + jsonObject;
        System.out.println(result);

        return Response.status(200).entity("\n\n\n\n POSTED ").build();



        Client client = Client.create();


        WebResource webResource2 = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/rest2/rest/hello/" +f);
        ClientResponse response2 = webResource2.get(ClientResponse.class);
        if (response2.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response2.getStatus());
        }

        String output2 = response2.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("\n<<<============  POSTING command to 3rd application");
        System.out.println(output2);
}   
}
```

So here basically am just posting a word from one application to another application. am getting an error saying Unreachable code in 
**Client client = Client.create();**

Could some one help me out with this error ?  or give some basic sample code where we POST word or data from one application to another

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: am using Jersey for this

Answer (score 0):

The formatting of the posted code is a bit strange, but if I'm seeing it right, the  compiler is telling that the `Client client` line is unreachable because of the `return` statement just before it.

Comment: Dear Rahul, i have edited it again. Thanks for your reply. If thats the case, how can i post the word to the 3rd application after the return statement ?

Comment: My pleasure. You probably want to move your return statement to the end of the method. Otherwise, the code after it won't execute (won't even compile), including the post to the third app. You might also want to wait until you have the response codes of the other app to decide the return code of this method's response.

Comment: It worked, after i moved the return statement to the end.. But the application is not ablt to POST it to 3rd application.. It shows the following error

Comment: Dec 24, 2015 7:55:30 PMo rg.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invokev SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with  ath [/RobotAutomation] threw exception  org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(Weba

Comment: Nice to hear it compiled. The second error you show is a runtime problem. The Java virtual machine cannot find the class `com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client` in the classpath. You need to look at your configuration and specifically the parameter `-cp` passed to java -- but I don't know it it's Eclipse, some other IDE, or a command line set up.